# Picture uploading issue using mobile device

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, mobile, file-upload

The main issue is that whilst **uploading a LARGE picture** (2.4mb) using a mobile device (iphone 4 in my case) I have to click upload twice, before it seems to actually work. However on the first click it does recognise something has been submitted and the loading icon spins about.

It's as if it's forgotten what it's doing until you click again? very strange. I would like to mention that it seems to work perfectly fine on desktop, and with small image sizes, just not mobile using large images. Why is this?

To get a better understanding go to petscovery.com/pictures **on your mobile device**

username: Test1234

pass: test1234

Hopefully it displays correctly, i've used flexbox and it's still in development

Thanks for any help/insight as to why it's doing this. I've only been coding for 6 months so it's quite probable I've overlooked something.

Comment: Like you said, 2.4mb is a LARGE upload for mobile

Comment: It's an image taken from an iPhone. I was hoping that it would be able to upload an image that has just been taken?

Comment: compress before send? TBH any experience i have had with ajax and images is v.slow even with smaller sizes..

Comment: it's not that it's slow ... it's that it SOMETIMES requires 2 submit clicks before it actually fires up and works.